# slicing lists not having the correct out come. Python 3

Tags: python, list, slice

I have some data in a file which i have converted in (int) 's and appended into a list.

```
minValue = open ("Mineral Values.csv", 'r')
refineList = []

for line in minValue:
    tritanium, pyerite, mexallon, isogen, nocxium, megacyte, zydrine, morphite = line.split(',')
    trit = int(tritanium)
    pye = int(pyerite)
   mexa = int(mexallon)
    iso = int(isogen)
    nocx = int(nocxium)
    mega = int(megacyte)
    zyd = int(zydrine)
    morp = int(morphite)
    refineList.append ([trit, pye, mexa, iso, nocx, mega, zyd, morp])
    minValue.close()
```

If i print this out it prints out all the data in the file. 
[[415, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [436, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [457, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [346, 173, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], etc etc

But i would like to slice a portion of these lists out so i can assign them to variables to do some math on. the code im using is the following

```
refineList[0:3]
print (refineList)
```

This should just print out 415 of the first list i thought? but instead it does nothing and just prints out the entire list again. Ive looked around on the site and all say using the slice method should work so what am i missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `map(int, line.split(','))` to save yourself all those individual calls to int.

Comment: You should be using `refineList = refineList[0:3]`. Just saying `refineList` doesn't change anything.

Comment: And to answer your question, no. There are several issues that you seem to be confusing. Using a slice *creates a new list* and doesn't modify the original. If you don't assign the slice to anything it simply gets garbage collected. Second, `refineList` is a list of other lists... The slice `[:3]` will return a new list with the first three sublists in `refineList`. If you want the first element of the first sublist, use `x = refineList[0][0]`

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[415, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [436, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [457, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [346, 173, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

print a[0] # print first list in my list of lists
print a[0][0] # print first element in first list in my list of lists

>>>
[415, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
415
```